# Is there a way to make a panel move slowly in Visual Studio using C#?

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio

I have coded a form where a panel moves when a button is clicked to the height of the clicked button. However, I want to make the panel move slowly instead of instantly.

> This is the code I have used:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MovePanel(btn1);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void MovePanel(Control c)
    {
        Panel.Height = c.Height;
        Panel.Top = c.Top;
    }
    private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MovePanel(btn1);
    }

    private void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MovePanel(btn2);
    }

    private void btn3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MovePanel(btn3);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a timer....

Comment: In Visual Studio?

Comment: yes its in visual studio

Comment: how do i use a timer in c#

Comment: So you want to move a Panel that is part of Visual Studio? (Pls use @[UserName] when you answer to comments, so that the person gets a notification)

Comment: @RandRandom i have already made the panel move using the code above. what i am trying to do is make it move slowly and smoothly. do you know how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would really like to see a timer-based solution from scratch.

In the meantime, you might check out something like dot-net-transitions, available on NuGet.

```
using Transitions;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        btn1.Click += btn_Click;
        btn2.Click += btn_Click;
        btn3.Click += btn_Click;

        MovePanel(btn1);
    }

    private void MovePanel(Control c)
    {
        var t = new Transition(new TransitionType_Linear(500));
        t.add(Panel, "Height", c.Height);
        t.add(Panel, "Top", c.Top);
        t.run();
    }

    private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MovePanel(sender as Control);
    }
}
```